# Image not showing in some react routes

Tags: reactjs, express

am working on a project were on can make a post with image but when ever i try to view a single post both the user profile and the post image do not show up and i get this server error.
         `http://localhost:3000/post/uploads/1577964281132Screenshot_20200102- 
        104724.png 404`

but am able to view it on this route.

```
http://localhost:3000/uploads/1577964281132Screenshot_20200102- 
 104724.png
```

on my express server i have this

```
app.use('/uploads' , express.static(path.join(__dirname , '/uploads')));
```

please is there any solution......

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did get the answer to  problems all I had to do was had a forward slash(/) to the image src value